# Replacing string around a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text file in which I want following replacements:

```
"type": "sql.NVarChar(100)",
```

with

```
"type": sql.NVarChar(100),
```

The **number inside NVarChar can be anything**. Can someone complete the following regex so that number remains as such:

```
schema = schema.replace(/"sql\.NVarChar(/g, 'sql.NVarChar('); // Incomplete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing group to capture the number, and use that in the replacement string.

```
schema = schema.replace(/"sql\.NVarChar\((\d+)\)"/g, 'sql.NVarChar($1)');
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^                   ^^
```

In this regular expression, `\d+` inside parentheses is captured and used in replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the quotation marks from the last segment, you could use [this](https://regex101.com/r/xF7sN3/1) regular expression: `"(.+?)":(\s*)"(.+?)"` and replace the content with this: `"\1":\2\3`.

Given this string: `"type": "sql.NVarChar(100)"` it would then yield this response: `"type": sql.NVarChar(100)`.